# What is causing static while I am recording?

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, audio-interfaces, home-studio

I am fairly new to recording and I am having an issue. I am using an AKG c214 Microphone, a Focusrite 2i4 interface, and running Fl studio.

I am getting a static/robotic sound when recording or playing back anything. Not just the input from the mic but all sound going to my headphones has the static. I tested my headphones and they work fine when not plugged in to the interface.

I should note that when I first set everything up, I had this same issue. Tried a few different recommendations then but nothing worked, eventually I came back to it and everything worked great.

Thank you in advance for any help!!

Comment: Post a WAV or an MP3 of the sound and maybe someone will be able to work it out.

Comment: I just checked to actual recorded audio, and it sounds fine. There is no static when I play it back by itself (I listened to it with the headphones plugged in my computer). I am only getting the static when using the interface.